# Is there a way to retrieve data from Firebase using the web API key and PostMan?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, postman

We are attempting to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database.

When we try the URL shown in Firebase to our project data using PostMan and add ".json" to the end like this...

```
 https://our_project.firebaseio.com/rest/our_data.json
```

...we get a "user not authenticated" error.

If we try to retrieve data using that URL using the web api key like this...

```
 https://our_project.firebaseio.com/rest/our_data.json?auth=[our web api key]
```

...we get a "could not parse token" error.

We are hoping that there might be some URL format like the above that could be used.

It appears the documentation suggests we need to get a token key. Unfortunately, when we look for how to get it - it [lists several methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) except a way to get it using simple GETS and POSTs via PostMan. We clearly are missing something in trying to understand the documentation.

Using PostMan, is there a sequence of GETs and/or POSTs that would enable us to retrieve data from Firebase?

Comment: "Warning: The ID token verification methods included in the Firebase Admin SDKs are meant to verify ID tokens that come from the client SDKs, not the custom tokens that you create with the Admin SDKs. See Auth tokens for more information."

Answer (score 1):

That documentation you linked to has nothing to do with the REST API you're using.  That's for verifying the identity of Firebase Auth users when they pass an ID token from a client app.  That's not what you're doing here.

The documentation Realtime Database REST API starts [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database).  The more specific documentation for authenticating your requests is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth).  Note that there are only two forms of auth listed here - Oauth tokens and Firebase ID tokens.  There is also legacy support for "database secrets" listed at the bottom of the page.  There is a link to click to get your secret, and *it is not a "web api key"*.  If you want to use that secret, be sure to read the warnings - it is deprecated and could stop working some time.

Bottom line here is that the "web api key" you have is almost certainly not one of the things you can pass in the auth parameter of the URL to get the API to work the way you expect.